# click listener for tab panel in EXTJS

Tags: extjs, tabs, listener

i use a tab panel in extjs. I want to display an alert when clicked on a tab. But i am not sure how.

This is what i do now:

```
{
                xtype: 'tabpanel',
                activeTab: 0,
                region: 'center',
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'panel',
                        title: 'All',
                        items: [grid]

                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'panel',
                        title: 'Closed'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'panel',
                        title: 'Open'
                    }
                ],
                 listeners: {
            click: function () {
                alert('test');
            }
                         }
            }
```

How can is display All, Closed or Open when there is clicked on that tab?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no event for tab click in `TabPanel`, however you can bind into click event on each tab:

```
Ext.createWidget('tabpanel', {
    items: [...],
    listeners: {
        render: function() {
            this.items.each(function(i){
                i.tab.on('click', function(){
                    alert(i.title);
                });
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Notice: this is ExtJS 4 based code.

Answer (score 0):

I manage to do this by using `tabchange` event. In example below I used `newCard.xtype` property where value of xtype (i.e. `task-archive`) is just my panel with controls and corresponding xtype property.

```
Ext.define('ComplexBrigade.controller.taskArchive.TaskArchive', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    init: function() {
        this.control({
            '#tabWorks': {
                tabchange: this.doTest
            }
        });
    },

    doTest: function ( tabPanel, newCard, oldCard, eOpts) {
        switch (newCard.xtype) {
            case "task-archive":
                console.log("task-archive");
                break;
            case "task-creation":
                console.log("task-creation");
                break;
        }
    }
});
```