# How to add tabs to a tabpanel in Ext Js

Tags: extjs

I have a tab panel in the center of the border layout. I want tabs to be added to the tabPanel when I click on the 'Add tab'. I tried using handlers and listeners both of which is not working for me. What is wrong with my code ?

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.Viewport',{
    extend: 'Ext.container.Viewport',
    initComponent: function(){
        var me = this;
        Ext.apply(me,{
            layout: 'border',
            items: [{
                region: 'west',
                width: '15%',
                title: 'West'
            },{
                region: 'center',
                xtype: 'tabpanel',
                items:[{
                    title: 'New Tab',
                    html: 'Tab content',
                    collapsible: true
                },{
                    title: 'Add tab',
                    listeners: {
                        click: {
                            fn: function(){  
                                console.log('hey i am here');
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    handler: function(btnPlus){
                        btnPlus.up().add({
                            xtype: 'panel',
                            title: 'New Tab'
                        });
                        console.log('hey i am here');
                    }
                }]
            }]
        });
        me.callParent();
    }
});
```

Also the Console messages are not getting printed :c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `tabchange` event and determine if the tab is the one representing the add new functionality

I would recommend using `insert` instead of `add` method because it provides the ability to set an index to add at

```
{
                region: 'center',
                xtype: 'tabpanel',
                listeners:{
                        tabchange:function(tabPanel, newCard, oldCard){
                            console.log(newCard.itemId);
                            if(newCard.itemId=='addNewTab'){
                                var addIndex = tabPanel.items.length -1;
                                tabPanel.insert(addIndex,{
                                    title:'Another Tab!'
                                });
                                tabPanel.setActiveTab(addIndex);
                            }
                        }
                },
                items:[{
                    title: 'New Tab',
                    html: 'Tab content',
                    collapsible: true
                },{
                    title: 'Add tab',
                    itemId:'addNewTab'
                }]
            }]
        });
    }
```

You will want to probably add an itemId to the add new tab panel so it will be easy to determine if it was selected.

Once you add a new tab it would also be useful to select the newly added tab. You can use `setActiveTab()` to set the new tab active.

Here is a [fiddle demonstrating working code](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/52m)

**Update:**

If you are going to allow `closable` tabs the above method may not work well.  This is because the `addNewTab` panel may be **automatically** selected **on removal of a tab** causing a new tab to be created.  Instead, adding a click event to the tab for addNewTab will work better:

```
{
                region: 'center',
                xtype: 'tabpanel',
                listeners:{
                    render:function(tabPanel){
                        console.log(tabPanel.down('#addNewTab').tab.on('click',function(){
                            console.log('added tab');
                            var addIndex = tabPanel.items.length -1;
                            tabPanel.insert(addIndex,{
                                title:'Another Tab!',
                                closable:true
                            });
                            tabPanel.setActiveTab(addIndex);
                        }));
                    }
                },
                items:[{
                    title: 'New Tab',
                    html: 'Tab content',
                    collapsible: true
                },{
                    title: 'Add tab',
                    itemId:'addNewTab'
                }]
            }]
        });
```

I have updated the [fiddle to show this approach](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/52m)

The idea for adding a click event came up from this [stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8985567/click-listener-for-tab-panel-in-extjs)

Comment: Thank you very much, it solved my problem. However if I add a closable: true config then it adds a tab instead of closing it

Comment: i added an update to the answer to show how you could set up if closable tabs are required by adding a custom event `click` to the `tab` of the `addNewTab` panel.

Answer (score 1):

There are not a "click" event for Ext.tab.Panel but you have a "tabchange" event where you can retrieve the selected tab.

[Here is the doc for this event](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.tab.Panel-event-tabchange)

If you are not using MVC in your app, you can register the listener into the tabpanel config :

```
{
  xtype: 'tabpanel',
  listeners: {
    tabchange: function(tabPanel, newTab, oldTab, eOpts)  {

        // You just have to check if the selected tab is the right one

        // here you code to add a new tab
        tabPanel.add({
            title: 'sometitle'
        });
    }
  },
  items: [{
    xtype: 'panel',
    title: 'Tab 1'
  }]
}
```